# sphinx4 an4 acoustic model not working

Tags: speech-recognition, sphinx4

I followed this [tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam)  using sample database [an4](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/databases/an4/an4_sphere.tar.gz) and tried to run TranscriberDemo(sphinx4-5prealpha) by using the acoustic model created using database mentioned above. But its not working I get errors.
I set the paths as follows

```
configuration.setAcousticModelPath("file:C:\\Users\\Thilini PC\\Desktop\\Result\\an4");

configuration.setDictionaryPath("file:C:\\Users\\Thilini PC\\Desktop\\Result\\an4.dict");

configuration.setLanguageModelPath("file:C:\\Users\\Thilini PC\\Desktop\\Result\\an4.lm.DMP");
```

I get following errors

```
 BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.940s
Finished at: Sat Nov 21 09:55:04 IST 2015
Final Memory: 5M/109M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project sphinx4-samples: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project sphinx4-samples: Command execution failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:377)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:610)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:352)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: This error has nothing about sphinx4. You just need to configure your IDE to run proper class. To learn more how to run Java classes, read IDE documentation.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev when I copied and pasted acoustic model found in the sphinx4-5prealpha-src\sphinx4-data\src\main\resources\edu\cmu\sphinx\models\en-us along with language model and dictionary to the same location C:Users\Thilini PC\Desktop\Result\, it worked. But that language model is in binary format. an4 language model is in DMP format. Is that the problem?

Comment: The real exception is above the lines you pasted then